# QGis, how to overlay and correctly position and scale a KML and image onto a Google base map

Tags: qgis, kml, overlay, png

Being totally new to the entire GIS subject I managed to install and get runnning QGis (2.2.0 on Mac) properly, get my Google Maps showing (I set the the CRS to WPSG:3857) and I also got my KML file of the island of Phuket.

Now I have to show the KML correctly positioned and scaled on the corresponding Google Map section of Phuket to then amend that KML with further details (KML needs a little fine-tuning, i.e. slight re-positioning of some of the coordinates to make them a bit more correct and I need to add to the island's outline also the inner "district boundaries".

Sorry for this so basic question, but any pointer to some links/tutorials where that subject (superimposing a KML/image, correctly positioned and scaled on top of a Google base map to edit a KML) is covered so that I can read and take it from there would be EXTREMELY helpful! Seems I don't have the proper pro's lingo yet as my Google searches don't really return any links which precisely enough cover that subject.

THANKS !

Comment: The KML layer should have EPSG:4326 as CRS, and `On-the-fly-reprojection` enabled. How much offset do you have?

Comment: The term you may want to try using in your searches is "georeferencing".